# CDH Hue and Hbase authentication

Tags: hbase, thrift, hue

I am new to CDH (Current version I used is 5.7.1)

I've added HBase thrift role and set up in Hue, but still I have the following problem.

[image: error image]

```
HBase Browser   Failed to authenticate to HBase Thrift Server, check authentication configurations.
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
hbase.thrift.support.proxyuser = false
```

this configure interface should be set false. I just solved this problem.

Answer (score -1):

In the CDH Hbase configuration interface, set the following three parameters

- hbase.regionserver.thrift.http = true
- hbase.thrift.support.proxyuser = true
- hbase.thrift.security.qop = auth

Comment: Can you please explain and clarify your answer? Can you also ensure that it is written in English.

Comment: I deliberately do not use English.23333~

Comment: The explanation of the answer:
In the CDH's hbase configuration interface, set the above three parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately the language of choice on Stackoverflow is English. There are version of Stackoverflow in other languages (eg [Russian](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/), [Spanish](http://es.stackoverflow.com/), [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)), but on this one we speak English. This has been discussed on Meta a few times, see for example  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291177/handling-questions-from-non-native-english-speakers

Comment: We cant update the configuration for hbase via the interface.